# A question on a countable discrete closed set

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups

Let $X$ be a topological group and let $D$ is a countable discrete closed subset of $X$. We also let $ \mathcal U= \{U_d: d\in D\}$ of open sets of $X$ such that witnesses that $D$ is closed discrete, i.e., for every $d \in D$, $U_d \cap D=\{d\}$.

> Is there a family $\mathcal W= \{W_d: d\in D\}$  of open sets of $X$ such that (1) $W_d\cap D=\{d\}$ for each $d\in D$; (2) $\overline{\bigcup W} \subset \bigcup \mathcal U$?

Thanks ahead.

Comment: I apologize for my initial answer, it's trickier than I thought! I'll think about it more carefully.

Comment: Okay. Thank you still:)

Comment: I'm trying to prove the stronger result: there is a basis of closed neighborhoods of $D$. Seems true to me but I can't prove it...

Comment: Alex’s answer is right, but it’s not obvious that there is a pseudocompact group that isn’t countably compact. You’ll find one in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1962-013-01/S0002-9939-1962-0133392-8/); it’s the group $K$ whose description begins at the bottom of p. $38$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the following.

:-) At the first sight this question is not related to my speciality. But at the second... Let $G$ be a pseudocompact topological group which is not countably compact. I leave to you the pleasure to do the rest.